# Store a changing jQuery variable to session or local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I currently have the following jQuery code working.  Here's what it does: when I click a button, it will swap between classes.  Each of those classes contains a background image.  So, as I click this single button, it cycles through the background images.  (edit:  I just need to store whatever the current variable is, so when they swap pages, that variable is what's loaded).

```
$('.button').mousedown(function () {
  $('#backgrounds').each(function(){
    var classes = ['bg1','bg2','bg3','bg4'];
    this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1)%classes.length];
  });
});
```

However, my website has multiple pages.  So, what I need to do is store the current variable to the session storage or local storage, and then retrieve that variable on page load.  That way as I jump from one page to another, the same class (and therefore background image) will be displayed.  I don't need to (nor want to) use cookies -- I just need this to last the current session.

Additionally, if possible (though much less important than storing the variable), I'd also like this jQuery function to neatly fade when swapping from one background image to another.  Right now it "snaps" from one image to the next as it swaps out the classes.

Thanks in advance -- any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The session storage API is pretty minimal; you can probably learn all you need from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: I'm assuming in my answer that `classes` is the variable you want to set to the browser storage. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I believe you're right, as `classes` is constantly changing and it needs to save whatever the current one is.  I really appreciate the input!  I'm quite new to jQuery and this level of web programming, though my HTML/CSS skills are decent.

Comment: Also, the `#backgrounds` selector grabs the element with Id `backgrounds`; there should only be one, so `each` doesn't really make sense in this case.

Comment: @this-vidor hmm, what would need to be used instead of `.each` ?  There's only one button with `#backgrounds`

Comment: @Frank78 I'll give my own answer with a simplified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `#backgrounds` should only match one element. So it is unnecessary to use `each`:

```
// Define classes & background element.
var classes = ['bg1','bg2','bg3','bg4'],
    $bg = document.getElementById('backgrounds');
// On first run:
$bg.className = sessionStorage.getItem('currentClass') || classes[0];
// On button click:
$('.button').mousedown(function () {
  // (1) Get current class of background element,
  // find its index in "classes" Array.
  var currentClassIndex = classes.indexOf($bg.className);
  // (2) Get new class from list.
  var nextClass = classes[(currentClassIndex + 1)%classes.length];
  // (3) Assign new class to background element.
  $bg.className = nextClass;
  // (4) Save new class in sessionStorage.
  sessionStorage.setItem('currentClass', nextClass);
});
```

In this demo I've used `getElementById` to select the `#backgrounds` DOM element, rather than selecting it using jQuery. This is because jQuery element representations don't actually have a `className` property, and the ordinary JavaScript API is simpler in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Also, the `getElementById` that you edited in got the swapping working.  I'm still trying to get the session storage part to work though.  **edit**-- `nextClass` did the trick!

Comment: There was a typo; I've changed the line `sessionStorage.setItem('currentClass', currentClass);` to `sessionStorage.setItem('currentClass', nextClass);`.

Comment: Thanks again -- this will definitely suit my needs!  My next step may be to add a fade effect when swapping between backgrounds, however, I would think the approach would have to be different since currently I'm swapping one class for another, and I can't "fade" between classes :)

Comment: I am not sure whether that is possible, if your images are all managed as CSS rules rather than independent `<image>` elements in the DOM. I suggest you ask this as an independent question—but I'm sure this one's been answered already on StackOverflow!

Comment: I was thinking the exact same -- not only would I need to update the script, but I'd have to probably move them to `<image>` elements stacked on top of each other or something, and fade one to reveal another.  I'll poke around SO to see what I can find;  else might post about it.  Thanks again, and cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) API for a single session.

Just set by getting the value from the `sessionStorage` if applicable (if not, set a default value):

```
var classes = sessionStorage.getItem(classes) || ['bg1','bg2','bg3','bg4'];
```

and set it when you need to:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("classes", classes);
```

Comment: Almost. I'm pretty sure the OP just wants to store the "current" class, not the list of classes.

Comment: @this-vidor OP didn't explicitly state which variable he wanted to store (hence my comment to the question), so I wasn't sure.

Comment: @this-vidor Actually, OP says yes, it is the variable he wants to store.

Comment: @this-vidor is right -- I should have clarified.  I just need the current classes stored so that when I swap pages, that class is loaded (and therefore, the correct background is loaded in)

Comment: @Frank78 I wasn't sure if the current class is stored in `classes`, so I just used that variable in my examples. If it isn't a pointer to the current class, make sure to change it in your code to the correct one.

Comment: Also, @Frank78: Welcome to SO! If this answer helped you, make sure to click the green check mark to the left of this answer to show the community that it solved your problem. Thanks!